# How to configure Xcode with BitBucket

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, xcode9

I have created a repo. on **bitbucket**. Now I want to connect that repo to the **Xcode 9**.So I can directly push, pull and do all the git stuff from Xcode.

is there  any way to do that?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the project folder is already on your computer, and is already under git control, skip this first step. Otherwise, use the command line, or Xcode's Source Control > Clone dialog, to clone your bitbucket repo onto your computer.
2. Open the project in Xcode and work with it.
3. There is no step 3! Xcode will see that this repo is under git control and you'll be able to use Xcode's built-in source control features as usual.

Comment: what to do, if i have a local Xcode Project, for which I want new bitbucket repo to be created and connected?

Comment: I tried to "add existing remote" https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git but pull got :"The remote repository could not be found"

Comment: @mica You're coming at this backwards. You need to get this onto bitbucket in some other way. Xcode isn't going to do it for you, and this is not an Xcode matter (it's simply about knowing how to use git). Then you can clone back and use Xcode management.

Comment: TNX: It works like this: 1) create empty project in bitbucket
2) in the local folder (holding the .git) connect with the bitbucket remote 
"git remote add origin https://account@bitbucket.org/account/PROJECT.git"
"git push -u origin master"

Answer (score 2):

I just spent an hour cajoling Xcode 9.2 into using a new Bitbucket git repo as a new remote.  I had trouble adding a new remote using the Bitbucket SSH URL since Xcode assumed my user name is "git" and did not allow me to edit it.  Here are some tips in hopes it saves you some time and aggravation.  This assumes you are already using Xcode's source control and have made commits locally on your Mac.  Make sure your commits are up to date before going through this procedure.

1. Create a new empty git repo on Bitbucket.  Do not create a readme at this point, as this would make your new repo not... empty.
2. Use the HTTPS address to access your Bitbucket repo from Xcode.  Problem is, for an empty repo, Bitbucket does not make it easy to figure out what this address is.  For me, it was the same URL Bitbucket shows for SSH access but replacing "git@bitbucket.org:" with "https://user@bitbucket.org/", with user@bitbucket.org (hopefully obviously) YOUR username.
3. In Xcode, open the Source Control Navigator.  This is the second icon from the left in Xcode's left panel next to the folder icon, it looks like a square with an x and a circle in the middle.  Right click "Remotes" and select "Add Existing Remote...".  Under "Remote Name" enter "origin" or "Bitbucket" or whatever floats your boat and under location enter the https:// URL from step 2.
4. Now, hooray, in Xcode you can do Source Control->Push successfully.

Thank goodness Apple does all my thinking for me, it saves me from hurting my little brain.  Now my only brain trauma is from banging my head against the wall dealing with this kind of nonsense.

Comment: Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add real Github* account to your Xcode under Xcode/Preferences/Accounts.

This will actually do authentication when you checkout Bitbucket project after that. I guess that they joined user databases.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as You had. To solve it I created a project with a git version control within Xcode 9 and then someone asked me to share it. To do it I created an empty repo on bitbucket, copied its address and then went in terminal to my project's directory.

```
cd ~/repos/<repo_name>
```

Once there you just have to write

`git push --mirror *copiedRepoAddress`

Make sure that  the repository you created at bitbucket is EMPTY and that you have commited all changes on your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below steps your project   will be   added automatically to bitbucket.

1.Go to Source Controller ---> create git repository
[image]

once click on create option.

2.Open your Bitbucket account and create new repository.And choose i have an existing project.
3.Select your repository address.
[image]

[image]

[image]